# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting wrong thing

Tags: angularjs

Getting this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 12; oldVal: 11"]]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…2fn%3A%20%24locationWatch%3B%20newVal%3A%2012%3B%20oldVal%3A%2011%22%5D%5D
    at chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at Scope.$digest (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12510:19)
    at Scope.$apply (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12736:24)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9811:22)
    at chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2843:10
    at forEach (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.eventHandler (chrome-extension://jiflmhpffanabaldnciipnblmfjcjado/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2842:5) angular.js:10023
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; old...<omitted>...5D
```

When I uncomment this code:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return document.querySelectorAll("span.joggleEmail")},function(newValue, oldValue){
            var emails = document.querySelectorAll("span.joggleEmail")

            angular.forEach(emails, function(span){
                // unbind the click, this is important for `mailto:`
                angular.element(span).unbind("click");

                angular.element(span).bind("click", function(){
                    console.log("Searching...");
                    $scope.$broadcast("searchServer", this.innerHTML);
                });
            })
        }, true)
```

No idea why and where I am including anything to do with `$location` for it to give me this error. Any idea how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes watching functions produces strange behavior that results in these kinds of situations. I am unfamiliar with querySelectorAll but it could be that whatever it is returning is changing too often. If it is possible to watch a variable instead of a function, that could solve the problem.